# VBA Object Required Error Trying To Get InnerText

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a code that will go to a website, put in data, submit it, and then return the answer to a cell in excel. When I step through it, it works fine, but when I just try to run it, I get run-time error 424; Object Required.

I tried looking for a good answer, but I am just not grasping on how to quite fix this. Where is my issue? How do I correct it?

```
Sub Distance()


Dim IE As Object

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' Make visible
IE.Visible = True

' Go to site
IE.Navigate "http://www.distance-cities.com/"

' Wait while IE loading...
Do Until IE.READYSTATE = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

IE.Document.getelementbyId("from").Value = "Stillwater, OK"
IE.Document.getelementbyId("to").Value = "Hollis, OK"
IE.Document.forms(0).submit

Do Until IE.READYSTATE = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'*Below is where I get my error
Sheet1.Range("E5").Value = IE.Document.getelementbyId("routemi").InnerText
IE.Quit

End Sub
```

I apologize if this is a bit messy.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: If it works when debugging but fails when run straight through, likely it's a timing issue and your page is not fully loaded, or the element you're trying to access has not been added to the page's content.  Try adding a short "wait" before trying to access the element in question.

Comment: Hi, I added Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")) and this did the trick, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can wrap the `getelementbyid()` in a loop until the return value is not `Nothing` (but you should also add a time limit on how long you're prepared to wait so you can break out of the loop if the element never appears...)

Comment: What would that look like?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (untested):

```
Dim el as object
'...

Set el = WaitForElement(IE.Document, "routemi", 1)
If Not el is Nothing Then
    Sheet1.Range("E5").Value = el.innerText
Else
    Msgbox "Element 'routemi' not found!"
    Exit Sub
End if
```

Utility function to get an element by id, waiting until it appears:

```
Function WaitForElement(doc As Object, id As String, maxWaitSec As Double) As Object
    Dim rv As Object, t

    t = Timer
    Do
        Set rv = doc.getElementById(id)
        DoEvents
    Loop While rv Is Nothing And (Timer - t) < maxWaitSec

    Set WaitForElement = rv
End Function
```

Comment: I am struggling to get this to work, where do I apply this? Sorry for the simple questions!

Comment: Replace the third from last line of your code with the first block of my example code, and include the function in your module.

Comment: Thank you, I got an Object Required error on `Set rv = doc.getElementById(id)`

Comment: In that case then you may also need to test if `doc` is Nothing

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave proper waits at each point (after `.Navigate2` and `.Click`) to allow for page loading. I use CSS selectors to target ids as modern browsers are optimized for CSS. Also, I updated method for page navigation to `.Navigate2`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Distance()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True

            .Navigate2 "http://www.distance-cities.com/"

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            With .document
                .querySelector("#from").Value = "Stillwater, OK"
                .querySelector("#to").Value = "Hollis, OK"
                .querySelector("[type=submit]").Click
            End With

           While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
           Debug.Print .document.querySelector("#routemi").innerText
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```